# value of the field is not used

Tags: java, eclipse

I got the above warning on eclipse just before `private  int count=0;`

Here is my code:

```
package synchronise;

public class Mysync {

    private  int count=0;

    public Mysync() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Mysync sync = new Mysync();
        sync.dowork();

    }

    public void dowork(){

        Thread mysync = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for(int i=0; i<2000; i++){
                    // System.out.println()

                    count++;
                }


            }
        });

        Thread mysync2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for(int i=0; i<2000; i++){
                    // System.out.println()

                    count++;
                }


            }
        });
        mysync.start();
        mysync2.start();

        try {
            mysync.join();
            mysync.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

How can I fix this? Why am I getting this error? I updated the code.

Comment: You declare two threads (mysync and mysync2 and then you don't do anything with them, meaning count is never incremented (i.e. count is "not used.").

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. You could use the value of `count` somewhere, while you increment `count` you don't have a get or a display or an `if` with it.

Comment: use public int count=0; for system out **count**

Comment: @SamDeveloper, we can access private variables from public methods. Do we need to explicitly add public ?

Comment: if you want to print then var must be public..

Comment: No, need to make it private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fix the warning, just use it.

eg.

```
System.out.println(count);
```

the warning will disappear.

The warning indicates when compile the code, the optimization may delete the **useless** code.

Here **useless** code means it has nothing to do with the **output**, since software is all about input 
and output.

Answer (score 3):

Your only usage for `count` is updating it - since you never actually **do anything** with this value, it can safely just be removed, together with the places that increment it.

Comment: after I added `System.out.println(count);` warning was disappeared thanks.