# Java - The value of the field is not used

Tags: java

I want to write a class AddressBookEntry to represent an entry in an address book. An object of the class should store the name, phone number and email address for one person. The class should have a constructor to initialise a new object to represent a person, and getter methods to access each piece of information.
Here's my code so far:

```
public class AddressBookEntry {

    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;

    public AddressBookEntry (String name, String phone, String email)
    {
        this.name=name;
        this.phone=phone;
        this.email=email;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhone (String phone)
    {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getEmail (String email)
    {
        return email;
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error

> The value of the field AddressBookEntry.phone is not used

and the same for email. I don't  understand what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Fairly sure that's a warning, and not an error. Know the difference. Looks like you've got some code problems like @manouti pointed out though anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [value of the field is not used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26317214/value-of-the-field-is-not-used)

Answer (score 2):

The getters should not have parameters:

```
public String getPhone ()
{
    return phone;
}

public String getEmail ()
{
    return email;
}
```

Note that you can use an IDE to automatically create getters and setters for you.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use tools of your IDE to generate gettter/setter methods, it is less error prone for you.
I mean if you are using Eclipse  right client->source->Settter/Getter section will give you to select fields to create corresponding setter/getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that method parameter is treated as a local variable. So when you pass String email as method parameter it shadows the field email. Your method will return exactly the same String you passed, not the field email.

That leads to warning you observe, your field variable email is never used.
Wrong implementation of setters/getters is explained in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The phone and email attributes are never used and you are warned about it.
The important thing is that you understand why they are never used.
If you write:

```
public String getEmail (String email)
{
    return email;
}
```

This means that getEmail will never return the value of the email attribute but the value received in input as parameter.
To solve the problem you have different options:
Option 1:

```
public String getEmail ()
    {
        return email;
    }
```

Option 2:

```
   public String getEmail (String email)
    {
        return this.email;
    }
```

Option 3:

```
public String getEmail (String emailFake)
{
    return email;
}
```

This is the rationale:

Option 1: the right way. You simply return the value of the email attribute.

Option 2: you return the value of the email attribute because you use the this keyword.

Option 3: you return the value of the email attribute because your parameters has another name.